# How to move a button to the left side using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-animate

I have a button inside a div whose width is 300px. When the button is clicked, I'd like the button move to the left side of the div and get disappeared in 1 second.

How would that be possible with JQUery?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you perhaps tried anything?

Comment: yes, I was trying the properties of the animate method. worked now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably depends on how the original position is assigned, but I think the following should work:

```
$('button').click(
    function(){
        $(this).animate(
            {
                'margin-left' : '-=200px'
            },1000);
        });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Zu7bn/).

To fade out, and remove, the button:

```
$('button').click(
    function(){
        $(this).animate(
            {
                'margin-left' : '-=200px',
                'opacity' : 0
            },1000,
            function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
        });
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Zu7bn/1/).

Answer (score 0):

try fadeOut() with combination of animate()

```
$("#element").animate({
   left: 0
}, 1000, function(){
    $("#element").fadeOut();
});
```